# dictionary from df with columns within a key

Tags: python, dataframe, dictionary

I have a df such as follows:

```
data = [['a', 10, 1], ['b', 15,12], ['c', 14,12]] 
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Name', 'x', 'y'])

  Name   x   y
0    a  10   1
1    b  15  12
2    c  14  12
```

Now I want it to pass it to a dict where `x` and `y` are inside of a key called `total`:
so the final dict would be like this

```
{
'Name': 'a',
"total": {
            "x": 308,
            "y": 229
        },
}
```

I know i can use `df.to_dict('records')` to get this dict:

```
{
'Name': 'a',
"x": 308,
"y": 229
}
```

Any tips?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try

```
my_dict = [{'Name': row['Name'], 'total': {'x': row['x'], 'y': row['y']}} for row in df.to_dict('records')]
```

Result:

```
[{'Name': 'a', 'total': {'x': 10, 'y': 1}}, {'Name': 'b', 'total': {'x': 15, 'y': 12}}, {'Name': 'c', 'total': {'x': 14, 'y': 12}}]
```

Or, if you wish to convert all columns except the 'Name' to the 'total', and provided that there are no repititions in 'Name':

```
df.set_index('Name', inplace=True)
result = [{'Name': name, 'total': total} for name, total in df.to_dict('index').items()]
```

With the same result as before.

Comment: Great! Then, there is no way to do it from the df itself?

Comment: Tried doing it directly from df, nearly impossible. I think this is one of the best solution by @JohanC.